# How to contact a moderator?

Tags: discussion

A recent question I posted was closed down and the only message I got was: "This question needs details or clarity. It is not currently accepting answers."

I have made some edits but I am not sure whether they meet the moderator's concerns. I cannot seem to find a way to contact the moderator to check whether my edits are ok or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### I have made some edits

That is the right thing to do.

> I cannot seem to find a way to contact the moderator to check whether my edits are ok or not.

You don't need to contact anybody.

From the link in the closed banner on your question:

> Questions that are edited within five days of being closed are automatically added to a reopening queue for community review. Closed questions can also be nominated for reopening by a user with sufficient reputation. If enough community members agree, the question will be reopened and can accept answers.

Source: [What does it mean if a question is "closed"? - Help Center - Super User](https://superuser.com/help/closed-questions)

Your question is a little clearer than it was, so I've reopened it for you, bypassing the reopen queue.